# how linq query bind to stimulsoft report

Tags: c#

I use stimulsoft for get report.first i design a report with stireport1 name.
but i click on button for report show , a empty report display for me.why?my code is:

```
private void radButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


           // stiReport1.RegData("query", query);
           // stiReport2.RegBusinessObject("PUBS", "pub_info", query);
            //stiReport2.RegData("pub_info", query);
          //  stiReport2.RegReportDataSources() = query;
           // stiReport2.Dictionary.Databases.Add(query);
           // stiReport2.Render();
            StiReport st = GetReport();
            st.Show();

    }

private StiReport GetReport()
    {
        StiReport report = new StiReport();
        if (File.Exists("D:\\stiReport1"))
        {
            report.Load("D:\\stiReport1");
        }
        PUBSEntities db = new PUBSEntities();
        var query = (from p in db.pub_info
                         select p).ToList();
        db.Dispose();
      //  report.RegBusinessObject("PUBS", "pub_info", query);

        report.RegData("mypub",query);
        return report;
    }
```

Comment: >a empty report display for me.why? : Only you can answer after debugging. There may be any number of reasons like empty data in pub_info, wrong implementation of report.RegData etc.

Comment: File.Exists("D:\\stiReport1")) <-- doesn't your file have an extension ? like .pdf or something?

Comment: try this: replace `.RegData("mypub",query);` with `.RegBusinessObject("mypub",query);`

Answer (score 0):

try to use next code:

```
  if (File.Exists("D:\\stiReport1.mrt"))
    {
        report.Load("D:\\stiReport1.mrt");
    }
```